# How can read from some files and write content of them with different form into files with same names

Tags: c++

I have some files with names f_1to2.txt, f_1to3.txt, f_2to1.txt, f_2to3.txt, ..., f_99to100.txt. I want to do something with the contents of these files and then write these changed files with the same names into another folder. How can I do it? thanks a lot.

Comment: It might be time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Do you know `std::fstream`?

Comment: This is a complicated task with a lot of different parts. It's completely unclear which part you are stuck on. Please post the code you have written already so we can help you with whatever you are stuck on. If you haven't written any code so far then now is the time to start. Write some code and when you get stuck you can post your code here to get some help.

Comment: sure. you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let us analyze your requirments.

- You have a list of file names.
- Source files are located in a source directory
- Then you want to read the files and modify them
- There is a destination directory, where you want to store modified files
- The destination file file names would be the same as the source file names

So, let us tackle point by point.

1. you have a source directory. We will store the source directoy path in a `std::string`.

One example could be: `std::string sourceDirectory("c:\\somedir1\\somedir2\\somedir3\\");`

2. Then you have a one or more filenames. Those can be stored in a vector of strings. For example `std::vector<std::string> fileNameVector{" f_1to2.txt","f_1to3.txt"," f_2to1.txt","f_2to3.txt","f_99to100.txt"};`.
3. Next activity is to open the files and do something with them. This you woould do in a loop. For opening textfiles to read we would use a `std::ifstream`
4. Destination directory will be stored in a std::string
5. Together with file names and the destination directory, we will build a path for the out files and open that with an `std::ofstream`

Skeleton example. Not real life code

```
for (const std::string& fileName : fileNameVector){
    std::string path = sourceDirectory + fileName; // Build a path
    std::ifstream inFile(path); // Open the file
    if (inFile) {  // Check if file could be opened
        std::string line{};
        while (std::getline(inFile, line)) { // Read all lines of text file
           // Store lines in vector
           // Do something

        }
        inFile.close();

        // Build output file path
        std::string destinationPath = destinationDirectory + filename;

        // Open out file
        std::ofstream outFile(destinationPath ); 

        if (outFile) {
            // Write all lines to output file
        }
    }
}
```

Please note. This is only a proposal for a solution. Nothing concrete. Not compiled and not tested skelleton code.

You need to fill in what you want to do.

This should just give an idea.

Your requirements are too vague, to construct a complete example.

So, just an idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, a good idea! Many thanks.